# Python: how to add different part of a text document to different arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to make a receipt creator where you "buy" products then go to the checkout to confirm you want to "buy" your items.(this is just a python program, you don't spend money).

However, i feel like this could become extremely easy for me if i could put the names of all of the items in one array, the GTIN 8 number into another and the price into a final array.

My problem is that I MUST use some sort of text document to store the items with their GTIN 8 number and their price. Is it possible to do this, and if so, how?

Here is an example of a document that i would use:

GTIN 8 NO.  NAME. PRICE.

66728009, NET, 10.00

74632558, OATMEAL, 5.00

05103492, FISHING ROD, 20.00

45040122, FISH BAIT, 5.00

20415112, MILK, 2.00

37106560, SHOES, 25.00

51364755, T-SHIRT, 10.00

64704739, TROUSERS, 15.00

47550544, CEREAL, 2.00

29783656, TOY, 10.00

Comment: Do you know how use CSV files?

Comment: Yes it is possible, and CSV is probably the way to go. But this question is currently too broad for SO rules...

Comment: I have never ran into a problem like this so I haven't used a CSV file before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your file is pretty much a CSV (You will have to change the headers to be separated by commas, not dots).

So for reading a CSV you can do:

```
FILENAME = `yourfilename.csv`
items_names = []
items_GTIN_8 = []
items_prices = []

with open(FILENAME, 'r', ) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=', ')
    for row in reader:
       # Here for every row, the headers of your csv will be the keys
       # of the row dict
       items_GTIN_8.append(row['GTIN 8 NO'])
       items_names.append(row['NAME'])
       items_prices.append(row['PRICE'])
```

After running this you will have 3 lists with the values. **Remember to change the headers of you file, because they will become the keys in the row dict (separate them by comma or what you want to use as delimiter in your file)**.

To learn more about reading csv files with python check this doc:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

;)

Comment: thank you, i tried this and it works just as I hoped

Comment: I'm glad to help @robtaxe (:

Answer (score 0):

Just read your text document, pick up rights informations, then put in in 3 differents arrays for name, GTIN, and price. Maybe you can show what your document looks like.